# How did Binet get to his matrix multiplication algorithm and where does he speak about it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, math-history

I would like to know how Binet got to his matrix multiplication algorithm and where (book, paper, etc) he first told the world about it.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to peruse some findings of of Oliver Knill (Harvard):
 [When was Matrix Multiplication Invented?](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/history/matrix/index.html)

You'll find a number of potential resources to dig further. It is mentioned that Binet discussed such an algorithm in a lecture dated November 30, 1812.

From Wikipedia: Binet is "recognized as the first to describe the rule for multiplying matrices in 1812."

If it's of any solace, you might like the quote you can find on the linked webpage:

> To give the history of linear algebra is a task that is as important as it is difficult.
>     --Nicolas Bourbaki, 1984

Comment: ouch!..what a pity! Unfortnately I had already got to that page..helpful (the page I mean) but yet not satisfactory..I wonder whether there's any trace of the text of that lecture around..I'm going to look up right now

Comment: @Matteo: You should have included that information in your question; that would have saved others effort and allowed them to provide you with new information more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

See

- J. Binet, [Mémoire sur un Système de Formules analytiques, et leur application à des considérations géométriques](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k433672c/f287.item), *Journal de l’École Polytechnique* **9** (1813), 280–354.

Binet gave this lecture on 30 November 1812, the same day Cauchy presented on the same result (now known as the [Cauchy–Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)); see

- A. L. Cauchy, [Mémoire sur les Fonctions qui ne peuvent obtenir que deux valeurs égales et de signes contraires par suite des transpositions opérées entre les variables qu’elles renferment](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k433673r/f31.item), *Journal de l’École Polytechnique* **10** (1815), 29–112.

Comment: Do these papers have DOI links? How persistent are these links?

Comment: i doubt it; papers before 1900s rarely have a DOI. these links are to pages run by Bibliothèque nationale de France; the national library of France, so they are pretty durable for internet links. though naturally links are never very durable, hence the entire journal citation is also given in the post.